# Compensating for BST when calculating difference between 2 times

Tags: java, datetime

I need some help or a pointer in the right direction.

I am trying to get the difference between 2 times. I am in UK on GMT with timezone set to adjust for daylight saving automatically.

When I preform the following it is always 1 hour out unless, I switch off automatically adjust for daylight saving.

```
String strDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date().getTime() - oldDate.getTime());
```

If I run the following there is not the 1 hour difference the 2.

```
System.out.println("Current time " + Formats.HOURMIN.formatValue(new Date().getTime()));
System.out.println("Old time " + Formats.HOURMIN.formatValue(oldDate.getTime()));
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java.util.Date class has no time zone attached to it yet confusingly uses your default time zone when rendering a string. I'm guessing this may be your problem. One of many reasons to avoid java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

---

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library makes this kind of work easier. Look at the [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), and [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) classes.

In contrast to a java.util.Date, in Joda-Time a `DateTime` instance does indeed know its assigned time zone.

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a way to describe [durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) as hours, minutes, and such in a `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` format. I use that in my example code below. Joda-Time offers other ways as well.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/London" );
DateTime dateTimeNew = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeOld = dateTimeNew.minusHours( 2 );

Period period = new Period( dateTimeOld, dateTimeNew );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeNew: " + dateTimeNew );
System.out.println( "dateTimeOld: " + dateTimeOld );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeNew: 2014-01-02T23:19:45.021Z
dateTimeOld: 2014-01-02T21:19:45.021Z
period: PT2H
```

Comment: Thanks I have done it using the Joda-Time option. I tried using the default java but still had the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

The cardinal rule for calculating time intervals when different timezones are involved is to make sure to convert the times to UTC before subtracting.

Each time, no matter what zone and DST offset is in effect at the time (pun somewhat intended), converts to a unique UTC instant.  Once you have the times in UTC, calculating the difference is a simple subtraction.  The result is time-zone-independent.